Changing the way when newly registered users can post questions
Has there ever been consideration given to the way how and when questions can be posted by newly registered users? 
I noticed that of late tons of unqualified, unrelated, and oftentimes way too trivial questions are being asked and that often by those who are unrelated to the financial services industry. 
An idea came to mind to potentially require newly registered users to first answer a question or two with at least one up-vote or more before questions can be asked. Sure, this may keep a qualified user from getting his burning questions answered on the same day but I feel that could potentially be a reasonable price to pay to avoid all that "noise" that crosses the tape recently, stuff that needs to be closed, migrated,...
Another alternative would be to change the FAQ to a quick quiz type of way, newly registered users have to answer 5-10 questions before they can fire away. The questions will heavily focus on bringing home the point that this forum is targeting those working in the industry or academicians that are clearly qualified to post and add value. I would potentially be willing to help formulate the questions if there is interest in such format. 
I just find the many questions that clearly violate the FAQ extremely annoying. 
Any thoughts?

My general impression is, that this stack exchange is moderated in a rather unwelcoming way, especially to students(the reason I never asked or answered questions). I see where you are coming from and that there are a lot of very basic questions that fill up the page, but the foundation of SE is the community and I feel that restrictions and the removal of questions won't fix this problem, but only keep the community small and the SE loses value.
The challenge is to find the balance between sticking to the rules and not making the impression to not appreciate someone who wants to participate.

@jenson_bo, I tend to disagree with your view, though I understand where you are coming from. I prefer a smaller but more targeted community over a large one but with lots of participants without real experience either on the theoretical modeling side or trading/risk management side. What annoys me is people posting questions of utterly unrelated content to quantitative modeling/trading. You also do not go to a Porsche car dealership and yell at the sales man inquiring why they do not sell Nissans. Such behavior gets the question shut down. That was not really my point btw.

I think this is the basic question (which seems to be answered by the FAQ): Is the focus more on quality or quantity? I can accept that the quality approach was chosen. But since there seems to be no way of catch those questions in advanced, I would suggest to work out standardized comments for off-topic, duplicate or too  basic questions that make the point clear while being more welcoming. You might not want the original poster to stay, but it makes a better impression on others stopping by.

On the topic of avoiding those "noise questions": Having good answers to some basic questions might keep other users from asking them (even though it gives the impression that this kind of questions are tolerated).

@jenson_bo, well I chose a few questions that I generally find to not really match with the format of this site to still answer if I believe the answer adds value but I would say I pick at most 1 out of 15-20 of such questions.

There is no mechanism in Stack Exchange to assess someone's skills before he posts a question, as much as I'd like that to be the case. So we're forced to deal with clean-up.
